# Show that $ a \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3 } \Rightarrow a^{2^{3-2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3} $

Tags: number-theory

Show that $  a \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3 } \Rightarrow a^{2^{3-2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3} $

Show that$  a \equiv 1 \pmod{2^4 } \Rightarrow a^{2^{4-2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^4} $

**Answer:**

$ a \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3} \\ \Rightarrow  a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3} \\ \Rightarrow a^{2^{3-2}}=a^{2^1} \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3} $

**Am I right?**

Comment: For generalization: See property$\#10$ of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

In general, if $a \equiv 1 \pmod m$,then we have $a^n \equiv 1 \pmod m$ for any $n$.

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine!
To generalise a bit, if $a \equiv1(\mathrm{mod}n)$, you see that $a^k \equiv 1(\mathrm{mod}n)$, and so $a^{k^l}\equiv 1(\mathrm{mod}n)$ whatever $k$ and $l$ are :)